# React + MUI + Tabs + Style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have some issue to change the way tabs are rendered with MUI and React.
Despite the numerous solutions found in the internet, none of them succeeded.
I am currently using the latest version of MUI

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
"@mui/material": "^5.9.0"
```

Here is the code snipplet, the source of my problem:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label='deals tabs'
      TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'white' } }}
      centered>
</Tabs>
```

I have tried a dozen of solutions to change the default color of the selected tab and I just kept failing.

Did someone had the same issue ?
Best regards.

Comment: In Our project we managed to use this: `TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "gold", height: "3px" }, }}` pretty similar to what you have though

Comment: It works for the background, but not for the text color

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `TabIndicatorProps`, Try selecting the selected tab css class using `sx` prop:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label='deals tabs'
  sx={{ "& .Mui-selected": { backgroundColor: "white" } }}
  centered>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this solution, unsuccessfully. But I have just realized that the problem was the white space between the & and the .Mui-selected. thx. ```sx={{ "&.Mui-selected": { backgroundColor: "white" } }}```

Comment: @Pueblo2708 do you mean that your problem is solved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the white space in the stylesheet, between the & and .Mui-selected:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label='deals tabs'
  sx={{ "&.Mui-selected": { color: "white" } }}
  centered>
</Tabs>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i wanted to customise the Tabs for the default, selected, hover and solved it using the code below. As you can see I am using the `sx` on the parent `<Tabs>`

```
export const tabSx = {
  '& .MuiTabs-indicator': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  '& .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiTab-root': {
    color: 'black',
    transition: 'color 0.2s ease-in-out',
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'green)',
    },
    '&.Mui-selected': {
      color: 'red',
    },
  },
};

            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              sx={tabSx}
              aria-label="test tabs"
            >
              <Tab label="Tab 1" {...a11yProps(0)} />
              <Tab label="Tab 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
              <Tab label="Tab 3" {...a11yProps(2)} />
            </Tabs>
```